# сортировка по параметрам при условии что дата больше сегодняшней

Tags: php, mysql

ломаю голову не могу придумать запрос к базе данных (mysql) в моем случае.

ситуация такова. у меня сайт с объявлениями. посетитель публикуя объявление может заказать его "поднятие". т.е. оплатив поднятие обяъвления на 5 дней, в течении 5 дней оно будет выдаваться первым в списке.

в таблицу с объявлениями я записываю дату когда оканчивается купленное поднятие. но как сделать запрос так что бы первыми выдавало объявления помеченные как купленные и что бы по истечению срока они снова выдавались в обычном порядке просто по дате создания объявления?

Comment: Делайте в запросе вычисляемый столбец через IF, который будет содержать 0 для поднятых объявлений и 1 для остальных и его укажите первым в ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
      * 
from ((select 
          *,
         '2' as tmpn 
       from t 
       where unix_timestamp(NOW())<=unix_timestamp(t.oplacheno))
      UNION
      (select 
          *,
         '1' as tmpn 
       from t )) 
       as tmp

group by i
order by tmp.tmpn desc,i asc;
```

Таблица из примера выше/ниже.

Answer (score 0):

пример:

в базе данных две записи, первая создана раньше, но оплачена по вчерашний день.

в первом запросе — требуемый порядок: та, что создана позже (вторая запись) — выведена раньше первой.

во втором запросе сэмулирована картина «вчерашнего дня», когда оплата ещё была актуальна: первая запись выведена раньше второй.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cea44/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (i int, sozdano date, oplacheno date);

insert into t values
   (1, '2015-01-01', '2015-09-01')
  ,(2, '2015-02-01', null)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select i, coalesce(if(oplacheno>=now(),
  oplacheno, null), sozdano) from t
order by 2 desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cea44/1/0)**:

```
| i | coalesce(if(oplacheno>=now(), oplacheno, null), sozdano) |
|---|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 2 |                               February, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| 1 |                                January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select i, coalesce(if(oplacheno>='2015-09-01',
  oplacheno, null), sozdano) from t
order by 2 desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cea44/1/1)**:

```
| i | coalesce(if(oplacheno>='2015-09-01', oplacheno, null), sozdano) |
|---|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 |                                     September, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| 2 |                                      February, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
```